# How to change build start folder in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins which is trying to build repo from git (everything is already prepared). But build returns failure - I suppose it tries to invoke gradle in folder below the folder contatining gradle files. How to change start folder for Jenkins ?

GitParentFolder/ - that's where jenkins is trying to invoke gradle

GitParentFolder/Folder2 - that's where it should invoke gradle

Comment: Jenkins clones the code from the repo to the workspace. To understand why your build fails you can check console of the failed build or post it here so we can further help you

Comment: found workaround - adding shell script before invoking gradle step build (cd Folder2). I know it's dirty hack but I couldn't find anything better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a Gradle build, use the [Jenkins Gradle plugin.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin)  This has a field "Root Build script" that lets you specify a directory where your build file is located.

Comment: I was using this plugin but somehow missed field "root build script" - thx for help